# MongoTemplate aggregate get distinct values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I'm trying to get a list of distinct elements as my final result in a MongoTemplate aggregate function. And I'm receiving a list like below at the middle of the aggregate,

```
[
   {
      "_id":"333",
      "name":"cat Three name",
      "description":"cat item description"
   },
   {
      "_id":"222",
      "name":"cat Two name",
      "description":"cat item description"
   },
   {
      "_id":"222",
      "name":"cat Two name",
      "description":"cat item description"
   },
   {
      "_id":"333",
      "name":"cat Three name",
      "description":"cat item description"
   }
]
```

How can I add another AggregationOperation to get distinct values as my final result like below?

```
[
   {
      "_id":"222",
      "name":"cat Two name",
      "description":"cat item description"
   },
   {
      "_id":"333",
      "name":"cat Three name",
      "description":"cat item description"
   }
]
```

Comment: Group by `_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two steps:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YlRX-43_qn1)

### Spring-mongo

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    ... // Your pipeline
    group("_id").first("$$ROOT").as("data"),
    replaceRoot("data")
);
```

Comment: Isn't there a single step where we can do this instead of grouping by property and then replacing the root property with value? :)

Comment: @Sandeepa To find distinct values, we need to group them :) You can skip replaceRoot if it's ok for you the output data within `data` field